# black color in function always, why?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want my text to get random color, for that I made a function but I do get always black color, this function should return a random color for me.

```swift
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var colorOfText = randomColorFunction()
    
    var body: some View {

        Text("Hello, world!").font(Font.largeTitle.bold()).foregroundColor(colorOfText) 
        
    }
}
```

```swift
func randomColorFunction() -> Color {
    let redValue    = UInt8.random(in: 0...255)
    let greenValue  = UInt8.random(in: 0...255)
    let blueValue   = UInt8.random(in: 0...255)

    print(redValue.description, greenValue.description, blueValue.description)

    return Color(red: Double(redValue/255), green: Double(greenValue/255), blue: Double(blueValue/255))
}
```

Comment: Maybe unrelated but why not `let redValue = Double.random(in: 0.0...1.0)`

Comment: I downvoted for using 8-bit color.

Comment: @Jessy: It would be nice not just going for down voted, RGB are between 0-255 and that is why I choose them.

Comment: @willy: I found your code is good for UIn8.

Comment: @willy That was the case back before we were born, sure. Stop using 8-bit color. It doesn't make any sense unless you're too old to be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the return of `randomColorFunction` to this:

```swift
return Color(red: Double(redValue)/255.0, green: Double(greenValue)/255.0, blue: Double(blueValue)/255.0)
```

your solution did not work, because the result of the division always return Int and it causes to be 0 or 1 that means black color or white color

Comment: Actually, if any of the the random 0...255 calls returns 255, the value of the division will return 1. About 3 out of 256 times, you'll get one color component at full  brightness. ≈Two out of 65536 times, you'll get two components at full brightness, and one out of ≈16 million times, you'll get white.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thank you for the point ;) my purpose was to explain why it's always got black color in this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is creating UInt8 values, and dividing them by the int value of 255. The result will always be an integer of 0 or 1. (and the odds are it will be 0 about 255 out of 256 times.)

You need to either use `Double.random(in: 0.0...1.0)` as suggested by Vadian, or cast your values to doubles:

```
let redValue    = Double(Int.random(in: 0...255))
let greenValue  = Double(Int.random(in: 0...255))
let blueValue   = Double(Int.random(in: 0...255))

print(redValue.description, greenValue.description, blueValue.description)

return Color(
    red:   Double(redValue/255.0), 
    green: Double(greenValue/255.0), 
    blue:  Double(blueValue/255.0))
```

Comment: thanks for help but I can choose one answer, he was the first one.

Comment: Yup, he pressed enter to post his answer a few seconds before mine. It's fair to accept the first correct answer.